# How to avoid repetitions when comparing two vectors by blocks

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl-algorithm

I am trying to compare two vectors which are of size of multiple of 4 and data is represented in terms of blocks (4 elements). Each vector block has a unique number it e.g {0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,2} or {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2} and {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1} so on. I am using iterator which increments i+=4 every time. I wrote a small function which do the job but the blocks tend to repeat. I am not sure how t0 remove repetition of these block. e.g vector_A {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} vector_B {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2} it should give local_vector1 {0,0,0,2} instead I get local vector_1 {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2}

```
void comparing_vectors_by_block(std::vector<int> vector_A, std::vector<int> 
vector_B)
{
const int blockSize = 4;
std::vector<int> local_vector1;
std::cout << "size of the vector_A: " << vector_A.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "size of the vector_B: " << vector_B.size() << std::endl;

for (auto it_A = std::begin(vector_A); it_A != std::end(vector_A); it_A+=4)
{
    for (auto it_B = std::begin(vector_B); it_B != std::end(vector_B); it_B += 4)
    {
        bool match = equal(it_A, it_A + blockSize, it_B, it_B + blockSize);
        if (!match)
        {
            std::cout << "match :" << std::endl;
            local_vector1.insert(local_vector1.end(), it_B, it_B + blockSize);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "not matched :" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a vector of "blocks", why not *make* it a vector of actual "blocks", like a vector of arrays (e.g. `std::vector<std::array<int, 4>>`)? Then comparison becomes just the normal `==` comparison operator.

Comment: Why are you outputting "match: " if it does not match and "not matched" if it does match?

Comment: I am not sure how vector of array works. I will have a look. it seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Match and unmatch is just for debugging. please ignore that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector of arrays of four ints to represent the data.
`std::vector<std::array<int,4>> vect1;`

If this data has some other meaning. It is better to use the OOP way and create
a struct or a class to represent that four numbers data. Then implement operator `==` and other helpful methods for the struct/class.

```
struct foo{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    ind d;
};
bool foo::operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
```

Then just iterate the vector and compare the elements using `==` like you would do if the vector was of type `int` for example.

```
for(auto& x : vector_A)
{
    if(std::find(vector_B.begin(), vector_B.end(), x) != vector_B.end()) {
         local_vector1.append(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to get the symmetric difference of two vectors of blocks. I.e. for A = {0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} and B = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2} you want to have local_vector1 = {0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2}.

In your implementation you compare each block of vector A with each block of vector B -- of course, you'll get extra mismatches. My (also non-optimized) solution:

```
std::vector<int> get_blocked_vectors_diff( const std::vector<int>& vector_A, const std::vector<int>& vector_B )
{
    const int blockSize = 4;
    std::vector<int> local_vector;
    for ( auto it_A = std::begin( vector_A ); it_A != std::end( vector_A ); it_A += 4 )
    {
        bool found_in_B = false;
        for ( auto it_B = std::begin( vector_B ); !found_in_B && it_B != std::end( vector_B ); it_B += 4 )
        {
            found_in_B = std::equal( it_A, it_A + blockSize, it_B, it_B + blockSize );
        }
        if ( !found_in_B )
        {
            local_vector.insert( local_vector.end( ), it_A, it_A + blockSize );
        }
    }

    return local_vector;
}

void comparing_vectors_by_block(std::vector<int> vector_A, std::vector<int> vector_B)
{
    auto A_mines_B = get_blocked_vectors_diff( vector_A, vector_B );
    auto B_mines_A = get_blocked_vectors_diff( vector_B, vector_A );
    auto local_vector1( A_mines_B );
    local_vector1.insert( local_vector1.end(), B_mines_A.begin( ), B_mines_A.end( ) );

    for ( auto a : local_vector1 )
    {
         std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Note, that we need two parts of the answer: A\B and B\A, so get_blocked_vectors_diff is called twice.

If you change your data structure like Petar Velev suggested, you will be able to shorten get_blocked_vectors_diff function:

```
std::vector<int> get_blocked_vectors_diff( const std::vector<Block>& vector_A, const std::vector<Block>& vector_B )
{
    std::vector<Block> local_vector;
    for ( auto& x : vector_A )
    {
        if ( std::find( vector_B.begin( ), vector_B.end( ), x ) == vector_B.end( ) )
        {
            local_vector.push_back( x );
        }
    }

    return local_vector;
}
```

Better solutions could be obtained if you sort your vectors of blocks first.

Comment: Thanks. It is very clear now. I will implement it by using proper data structure.